# getutent and Linux timer issues

Tags: c, linux, posix, system-calls

I have a problem running the below code , which invokes getutent() to count the total number of users currently logged in to the system. The timer will be invoked every 1sec and will set the boolean named "isSigAlrmOccured" to true and exit.The main function checks whether the timer signal is delivered by checking this boolen and monitor the number of loggedin users. Unfortunately, the timer signal is delivered to the main program only two times correctly and I don't get any further signals after that. The pause function call doesn't get interrupted after the first two signals.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <utmp.h>
#include <errno.h>

static int isSigAlrmOccured;

void alarm_handler (int signo)
{
  static int i=1;
  printf("\n Signal Occurred %d times\n",i++);
  isSigAlrmOccured = 1;

}

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
   struct itimerval delay;
   struct utmp *utmpstruct;
   int numuser;


   int ret;
   signal (SIGALRM, alarm_handler);
   delay.it_value.tv_sec = 1;
   delay.it_value.tv_usec = 0;
   delay.it_interval.tv_sec = 1;
   delay.it_interval.tv_usec = 0;
   ret = setitimer (ITIMER_REAL, &delay, NULL);
   if (ret) {
     perror ("setitimer");
     return 0;
   }
   for (;;) {
       pause ( );
       /* count the number of users */
       if ( (errno == EINTR) && (isSigAlrmOccured) ) {
           isSigAlrmOccured = 0;
           setutent();
           while ((utmpstruct = getutent())) {
           if ((utmpstruct->ut_type == USER_PROCESS) &&
               (utmpstruct->ut_name[0] != '\0'))
               numuser++;
           }
           endutent();
       }
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Output:

Signal Occurred 1 times

Signal Occurred 2 times

Comment: Why not just call `sleep(1);` instead of `pause()` and all the signal stuff?

Answer (score 7):

The implementation of *utent() is using alarm() and is reseting your alarm.
You'll have to do something else.

strace ttest    ( some lines removed for brevity )
[...]
pause()
--- SIGALRM (Alarm clock) @ 0 (0) ---
write(1, " Signal Occurred 1 times\n", 25 Signal Occurred 1 times) = 25
open("/var/run/utmp", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
alarm(0)                                = 5
rt_sigaction(SIGALRM, {0x7f52580a91c0, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x7f5257fd46e0}, {0x40075c, [ALRM], SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, 0x7f5257fd46e0}, 8) = 0
alarm(1)                                = 0

Example code which only sets the alarm during the sleep period.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <utmp.h>
#include <errno.h>

static int isSigAlrmOccured;

void alarm_handler (int signo)
{
  static int i=1;
  printf("\n Signal Occurred %d times\n",i++);
  isSigAlrmOccured = 1;

}

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
   struct itimerval delay;
   struct utmp *utmpstruct;
   int numuser;
   int ret;

   for (;;) {
   signal (SIGALRM, alarm_handler);
       alarm(1);       /* wake me later */
       pause ( );
       /* count the number of users */
       if ( (errno == EINTR) && (isSigAlrmOccured) ) {
       signal (SIGALRM, SIG_DFL);
           isSigAlrmOccured = 0;
           numuser = 0;
           setutent();
           while ((utmpstruct = getutent())) {
           if ((utmpstruct->ut_type == USER_PROCESS) &&
               (utmpstruct->ut_name[0] != '\0'))
               numuser++;
           }
           endutent();
           printf("found %d users\n", numuser);
       }
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks codeDr. That seems to be the problem. To overcome this, Iam resetting the signal handler and setitimer at the end of for-loop 
each time.Is there any better way to do this ? One better alternative that I could think of is to go with timer_create and sigaction calls and define my own SIGUSR signal.

Comment: You should use timer_*, alarm, or sleep instead, since setitimer has been marked obsolescent by POSIX: http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/setitimer.html#tag_16_202_07

Answer (score 1):

[This page](http://linux.die.net/man/2/signal) lists the set of functions that are "safe" to call from a signal handler. If you call some other function, the behavior is undefined. I notice that `setutent()` doesn't seem to be on the lest, for starters ...

Comment: Hi unwind,
 I moved the function call outside the context of timer ( see the changed code above ) , but it's doesn't work either.

Comment: `printf()` is not async-signal-safe either.  Also `printf()` can change `errno`, but your signal handler does not save it at the beginning and restore it before returning.